# No pagerank on sites-listing pages in Directories

Tags: seo, directory-listing

I started researching directories to add my website and noticed a pattern - in every directory the page with links to websites has no Pagerank, while a page one level above can have quite high Pagerank.
For example:

http://dir.yahoo.com/entertainment/music/artists/arrangers/ - no PR.

http://www.submissionwebdirectory.com/computers_and_internet/product_information_and_reviews/ - no PR.

In both cases a page one level above has PR5 (sorry I can't post more links due to my new account low rep)

Does Google deliberately do this to discourage us to use directories for links? Does it mean that there is no link juice from such pages?

Comment: How are you determining the PageRank of these pages and sites? That may help us answer your question.

Comment: I mean toolbar pagerank

Comment: Okay. I am not sure how reliable toolbars are. There are complaints even about the Google toolbar. Your question is a correct and very good question. Often, directories are not the best place to get backlinks. I know that SEOs recommend this, but the SEO winds have changed lately and the new SEO philosophy seems to be not to seek backlinks from directories with a few exceptions, such as Yahoo! and DMOZ. I will let someone answer the question. As I sit here, I would have to think on this for a bit to give a complete answer even though the answer is rather simple.

Comment: FYI, [Google considers links from low quality directories to be low quality links.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en). Seeking these links would *not* be a judicious use of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this from 2008 which appears to be exactly what you are seeing: http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/017333.html

There is a partial answer here linked from the previous page: http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/017363.html

This answers your question specifically for the situation you are seeing. A deeper explanation could be made about PageRank throughout a site and that is good and valid information. However, this answer speaks specifically to the phenomenon of the Google toolbar not recognizing PageRank for Yahoo!.

Answer (score 0):

These sites have thousands of links in them, so any page rank is soon going to get diluted.

In your example, http://www.submissionwebdirectory.com/computers_and_internet is linked to from every page of that site and so would be expected retain quite a bit of the page rank sloshing around, but http://www.submissionwebdirectory.com/computers_and_internet/product_information_and_reviews/ is only linked to from one page which has over 250 other links on it.  If not a zero page rank, it would still be expected to at least have a very low one.

Whilst Yahoo won't harm you as they are a big brand, people using directories for page rank were hit by Google's penguin update, and so I'm pretty sure you would be risking a penalty by using untrusted directories.